# Need to convert time into number using ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have a table called DATA which has these two columns:-

TaughtDistinct  - varchar

ValueofTaught   - numeric(2,2)

Taught distinct holds a time for example 07:30 but I need that in the ValueofTaught column as 7.5.

[image]

I just cant work it out, I have tried the below query:-

```
select * from CQData2

--Add temporary column TempValueOfTaught
alter table CQData2 add TempValueOfTaught Numeric(5,2)


--Update temporary column with values from ValueOfTaught
update CQData2 set TempValueOfTaught = ValueOfTaught


--Set ValueOfTaught to null
update CQData2 set ValueOfTaught = NULL


--change data type of ValueOfTaught to numeric
alter table CQData2 alter column ValueOfTaught NUMERIC(5,2)


--Ensure TempValueOfTaught is returning numeric values only
Select * from CQData2 where ISNUMERIC(TempValueOfTaught)=0


--Update ValueOfTaught using TempValueOfTaught values
update CQData2 set ValueOfTaught = Cast(TempValueOfTaught as numeric (5,2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is consistent in format with your example (especially, the leading zero for single digit hours), here's a quick proof of concept...

```
DECLARE @MyTime varchar(max)

SET @MyTime = '07:30'

SELECT 
    @MyTime, 
    CONVERT(real, LEFT(@MyTime, 2)) + (CONVERT(real, RIGHT(@MyTime, 2)) / 60.0) AS [ValueOfTaught]
```

For the update...

```
UPDATE 
    CQData2 
SET 
    ValueofTaught = ROUND(CONVERT(real, LEFT(TaughtDistinct, 2)) + (CONVERT(real, RIGHT(TaughtDistinct, 2)) / 60.0), 2)
WHERE
    ValueofTaught IS NULL
```

Note that I changed the data type from `numeric(2,2)` to `real` in my code.  The [numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) data type with Precision and Scale both set to two will never be able to hold a value greater than or equal to one.

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebb0fa/2/0) of the whole deal, including as much sample data as was visible in the OP.

Comment: Thats great its changing it to what i want but how can i take this and do it automatically for each row in the Data numbed instead of setting MyTime manually?  Probably really silly question just SQL really isnt my strong point.

Comment: SELECT [TaughtDistinct]

FROM Data

DECLARE @ MyTime varchar(max)

SET @MyTime = [TaughtDistinct]

SELECT
    @ MyTime, 
    CONVERT(real, LEFT(@MyTime, 2))+ (CONVERT(real, RIGHT(@ MyTime, 2)) / 60.0) AS [ValueOfTaught]

Comment: Edited answer to include one update statement to populate ValueofTaught in all records that presently have `NULL` in that field.

Comment: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.
ERROR MESSAGE do i need to change my data types?

Comment: Yes, numeric(2,2) is too small - augmented explanation of data type change added to answer.

Comment: So i changed the data type of valueoftaught to real and taughtdistinct is still sitting as varchar but still same thing happening, I dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, my update statement still had the numeric(2,2) in there - changed it to reflect the select.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82106/discussion-between-ldmjoe-and-alexandria).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the new time-Datatype to be more flexible with your Format:

```
DECLARE @MyTime1 varchar(max) = '07:30'
DECLARE @MyTime2 varchar(max) = '7:30'
DECLARE @MyTime3 varchar(max) = '7:30:00'

SELECT @MyTime1 as style1 
      ,DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(time(0),@MyTime1))
       + DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(time(0),@MyTime1))/CONVERT(real,60.0) AS [Hours1]
      ,@MyTime2 as style2, 
      ,DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(time(0),@MyTime2))
       + DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(time(0),@MyTime2))/CONVERT(real,60.0) AS [Hours2]
      ,@MyTime3 as style3, 
      ,DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(time(0),@MyTime3))
       + DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(time(0),@MyTime3))/CONVERT(real,60.0) AS [Hours3]
```

Result:

```
style1   Hours1   style2   Hours2   style3   Hours3
07:30    7,5      7:30     7,5      7:30:00  7,5
```